# what does the '?' does in the return statement

Tags: javascript

The code is supposed to return the next square if current number is perfect square

```
function findnextsquare(sq)
{
    return Math.sqrt(sq)%1?-1:
    Math.pow(Math.sqrt(sq)+1,2);
}
```

Comment: It is basically an else statement...also called ternary operator

Comment: This way you can read it in a better way `return Math.sqrt(sq)%1?-1:    Math.pow(Math.sqrt(sq)+1,2);`

Comment: So, if this part `Math.sqrt(sq)%1` becomes true, then your function returns -1, else the Math.Pow part.

Comment: ? Is basically used as shorthand of if else statement. It is called Ternary Operator.    Syntax: (condition) ? true : false;